# Why isn't Rstudio inheretting exported LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: r, environment-variables, rstudio

We use lmod and modules to manage software on a RHEL 8.6 computer cluster.

In terminal 1, I load `R/4.3.0` and check both `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PATH`

```
$ ml load GCC/9.3.0  OpenMPI/4.0.3 R/4.3.0
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH  # This has been exported
/export/apps/opt/R/4.3.0-foss-2020a/lib64/R/lib:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/Java/11.0.2/lib:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/OpenMPI/4.0.3-GCC-9.3.0/lib:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/UCX/1.8.0-GCCcore-9.3.0/lib:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/hwloc/2.2.0-GCCcore-9.3.0/lib:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/libpciaccess/0.16-GCCcore-9.3.0/lib:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/libxml2/2.9.10-GCCcore-9.3.0/lib:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/XZ/5.2.5-GCCcore-9.3.0/lib:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/numactl/2.0.13-GCCcore-9.3.0/lib:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/binutils/2.34-GCCcore-9.3.0/lib:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/zlib/1.2.11-GCCcore-9.3.0/lib:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/GCCcore/9.3.0/lib64:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/GCCcore/9.3.0/lib
$ echo $PATH  # This has been exported
/export/apps/opt/R/4.3.0-foss-2020a/bin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/Java/11.0.2:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/Java/11.0.2/bin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/OpenMPI/4.0.3-GCC-9.3.0/bin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/UCX/1.8.0-GCCcore-9.3.0/bin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/hwloc/2.2.0-GCCcore-9.3.0/sbin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/hwloc/2.2.0-GCCcore-9.3.0/bin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/libxml2/2.9.10-GCCcore-9.3.0/bin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/XZ/5.2.5-GCCcore-9.3.0/bin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/numactl/2.0.13-GCCcore-9.3.0/bin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/binutils/2.34-GCCcore-9.3.0/bin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/GCCcore/9.3.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

I then load `/usr/bin/rstudio` version 2023.03.0+386 (installed via RPM) and then click on the Terminal window within Rstudio and check `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PATH`

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/export/apps/opt/R/4.3.0-foss-2020a/lib64/R/lib:/usr/local/lib64:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/Java/11.0.2/lib/server
$ echo $PATH
/export/apps/opt/R/4.3.0-foss-2020a/bin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/Java/11.0.2:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/Java/11.0.2/bin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/OpenMPI/4.0.3-GCC-9.3.0/bin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/UCX/1.8.0-GCCcore-9.3.0/bin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/hwloc/2.2.0-GCCcore-9.3.0/sbin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/hwloc/2.2.0-GCCcore-9.3.0/bin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/libxml2/2.9.10-GCCcore-9.3.0/bin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/XZ/5.2.5-GCCcore-9.3.0/bin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/numactl/2.0.13-GCCcore-9.3.0/bin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/binutils/2.34-GCCcore-9.3.0/bin:/gpfs0/export/apps/easybuild/software/GCCcore/9.3.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin:/usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/postback:/usr/bin
```

**QUESTION**

1. Why isn't Rstudio inheriting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set within terminal 1?  It has no problem with `PATH`

**UPDATE**

This appears to be related to [this](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12585) issue identified on github.